# POSIX like mutexes in WIN32

Tags: c, winapi, posix, ipc, mutex

Is there any equivalent of POSIX mutexes in Win32 ?

i need mutex modes (Recursive, Error Check) in Win32 named mutexes, but there is no way to use them on Win32.

or is there anyway to implement them ?

Comment: Critical sections are recursive, mutex objects are not.

Comment: I need named Recursive and Error Check mutexes, CRITICAL_SECTION's are anonymous

Comment: Thanks @RbMm, do you have any link or reference about how to implement them using Normal Mutexes ?

Comment: Yes they should be process shared.

Comment: I can't see anywhere in your question where you say you need named objects

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "*Critical sections are recursive, mutex objects are not*" - Win32 mutex are recursive: "*After a thread obtains ownership of a mutex, it can specify the same mutex in repeated calls to the wait-functions without blocking its execution. This prevents a thread from deadlocking itself while waiting for a mutex that it already owns. To release its ownership under such circumstances, the thread must call ReleaseMutex once for each time that the mutex satisfied the conditions of a wait function.*"

Comment: @KoLiBer see [Mutex Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/mutex-objects) on MSDN. Win32 mutexes can be named for cross-process sharing, and are recursive. Error checking can easily be implemented in your own code when (un)locking a mutex

Comment: @RemyLebeau Oh, so default type of Win32 mutexes is Recursive.., I thought their premise was Normal mode, thanks a lot bro